# Unable to install auto-py-to-exe; Coudn't find a version

Tags: python, pip, auto-py-to-exe

I am unable install auto-py-to-exe

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cffi>=1.12.3 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for cffi>=1.12.3
```

I would be glad if anyone could help me. Thank you

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: How are you trying to install it?

Comment: I am using windows 10. I install it on the terminal of the pycharm

Comment: This is probably not the complete output. Please post the command you are running as well as the complete output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many things that may be causing this issue. First - check that your operating system is fully up-to-date. Second upgrade your `pip` with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Next you should check that your setup tools are up-to-date with `pip install --upgrade setuptools`. If your setup tools are up-to-date you will simply get the message `Requirement already up-to-date:` - the version should be `(46.1.3)`. Next - this probably won't have any issues as you are not getting the error `Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output` - you should install [gevent](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/) with `pip install gevent`. You should also install [cffi](https://pypi.org/project/cffi/) or update it with `pip install cffi`. Also use the original cmd by typing cmd in Cortana and running the cmd as administrator:

[image: This cmd]

If this doesn't work then comment and i'll have another look.

Comment: I have already upgrade my 'pip'. However, in the terminal it always appeared as 'You are using pip version 10.0.1, however version 20.0.2 is available. You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.' my 'setup tools' already upgraded. And I can't install 'gaven' and 'cffi'. Thank you

Comment: @Michael . According to your error you need cffi. You can not install auto-py-to-exe without gevent. Upgrade your pip with the command in cmd as instructed in answer. If you recive requirement already satisfied then you are fine. You must have these installed so you must try and respond with the error if you have one.